# store a function in a unix variable

Tags: function, shell, unix

I am a newbie to unix. I am wondering if there is any way to assign a function to a unix variable, like:

```
temp=funcname(){echo 'I am in function'};

$temp; // prints I am in function.
```

Please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions are not first-class in UNIX shells. However, you can store the name of your function in a shell variable and call it thereby.

```
funcname_foo() {
  echo "I am a function"
}
temp=funcname_foo
"$temp"
```

That said -- if you wanted to point to a different function conditionally, you could just as easily define it conditionally:

```
if [ "$foo" = bar ] ; then
  funcname() { echo "Function A"; }
else
  funcname() { echo "Function B"; }
fi
funcname # actually call the function
```

It *is* possible to define a function using text from a variable through use of `eval`; however, this is [error-prone and contrary to best practices](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048), and generally should not be done.

If you described your actual use case, a better example of the right way to achieve your desired result should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

No. Functions are not first-class in traditional *nix shells.

Answer (score 0):

Use function e.g. in the bash shell:

```
function manhtm { man -R=ASCII $1 | rman -f HTML > ~/tmp/$1-man.html && firefox ~/tmp/$1-man.html;}

function rff { sudo rfcomm connect $1;}
```

Comment: Raw POSIX doesn't require or support the `function` keyword at the beginning of a function definition (and bash, while supporting it, doesn't require it either!)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy True, but I think it more expressive this way and it is not illegal to add

Comment: in purely standards conformant POSIX sh, yes, it _is_ illegal. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_05

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the link but i was referring to bash:http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html

Comment: The question is tagged for UNIX shell, not bash.

Comment: OP is a newbie, today's standard shell on most linux systems is bash

Comment: Only for interactive use -- for scripts tagged `#!/bin/sh`, the default shell on Debian derivatives is dash.

Comment: Also, there's a reason irc.freenode.org#bash doesn't point people at TLDP documentation -- they don't have a good reputation for accuracy, despite having plenty of Google juice (think of them as the shell-scripting equivalent of W3Schools). http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide is very much preferred.