# Linux shell fails to call a function via dollar operator

Tags: bash, shell

Using the latest Ubuntu default shell (bash-compatible) I can create an one-line function and call it:

```
$ foo() { echo bar; }; foo
bar
```

But if I create a string with the  same command and execute it via `$`, function is not called. What part of shell function syntax do I not understand?

```
$ FOO='foo() { echo bar; }; foo'
$ echo $FOO
foo() { echo bar; }; foo
$ $FOO
-bash: foo(): command not found
```

Comment: you are probably looking for `eval`.

Comment: Please check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198622/store-a-function-in-a-unix-variable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parameters store data, not code. You haven't defined a function; you've just created a string that looks like a function definition and a call.

You might be confusing it with something like

```
$ FOO="echo bar"
$ $FOO
bar
```

which contains a command name and its argument. When `$FOO` is expanded, the resulting stream of words is then looked at to identify which word is in command position and which words are arguments. However, a function definition isn't a command; it's special syntax that isn't subject to the normal evaluation strategy of a command line.

Your example isn't a single command: it is a command *list*, which is one or more commands separated by `;`, `&`, `&&`, or `||`.

Finally, `$` doesn't execute anything; it simply begins a parameter expansion. Whether the result of the expansion is executed depends on the context in which the expansion occurs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That mean, that function definition is a "special syntax" that works differently during "normal evaluation" and "evaluation after parameter expansion"? Is it written somewhere, or just an implementation details?

Comment: Got it, ';' and '&' doesn't play well together. `FOO='echo a; echo b'; $FOO` will echo "a; echo b". Thanks a lot!